# Difference in meaning of these terms: Dataset vs Corpus

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, terminology, definition

I have a question pertaining to definition of terms that I couldn't find answer for.

What's the difference between Dataset and Corpus?

I've seen them being used almost interchangeably. My understanding is that Corpus (meaning collection) is broader and Dataset is more specific (in terms of size, features, etc).

Please let me know what you think. I apologize in advance if this isn't the right forum for this question. The reason I have a doubt is because my adviser and I are having a confusion on what is most suitable for our paper titled: "Techniques to extract XX from multimedia corpus/dataset"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think "corpus" mainly appears in NLP area or application domain related to texts/documents, because of its meaning "a collection of written texts, esp. the entire works of a particular author or a body of writing on a particular subject." (https://www.google.com/search?q=define+corpus)

In contrast, dataset appears in every application domain --- a collection of any kind of data is a dataset.

Update:
Please check [this webpage](http://language.worldofcomputing.net/linguistics/introduction/what-is-corpus.html) , it is said that

"Corpus is a large collection of texts. It is a body of written or spoken material upon which a linguistic analysis is based. "

Answer (score 3):

I'll cite аn article in the Qualitative Research area:  "Data corpus refers to all data collected for a particular research project, while data set refers to all the data from the corpus that is being used for a particular analysis."
see [Braun, Virginia and Clarke, Victoria (2006) Using thematic analysis in psychology. Qualitative Research in Psychology, 3 (2). pp. 77-101. ISSN 1478-0887](https://uwe-repository.worktribe.com/output/1043060/using-thematic-analysis-in-psychology)